# Meteor + MongoDB: Database pattern

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router, simple-schema

I'm new to Meteor and trying to figure out how to best design this database to store and publish data. I thought it would make sense to use these packages:

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router

I'd have a collection for the list of courses to be listed on a page:

```
Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");

Courses.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
  },
  comingSoon: {
    type: boolean,
    label: "Coming Soon?"
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    label: "Course Description",
    max: 200
  }
}));
```

And a collection for the lessons inside each course:

```
Lessons = new Mongo.Collection("lessons");
Lessons.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
  },
  video: {
    type: String,
    label: "Link to video"
  },
}));
```

and have a admin page to create new courses/lessons using the autoform package.

My questions is how would I link the course to the lessons related to it? Would I use iron:router to listen to parameters in the url and query both collections and create the template layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a field corresponding to the Lesson / Course relation, similarly as in traditional databases.

For example:

```
Lessons.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  courseId: {type: String}, // ID of the corresponding course
}));
```

or:

```
Courses.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  lessonIds: {type: [String]}, // Array of IDs of lessons
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended pattern used for mongodb is to have denormalization in your database.

What it means simply is that you don't have any `relational` db pattern. In SQL, you have relational database paradigm and to fetch a detailed data you need to do `Join` with tables. In mongodb, instead of putting a reference in your document(row), you put the whole object here. so there's no `join` actually.

so in your lesson schema you can do something like this,

`Schemas.Course = new SimpleSchema(...);`

```
course: {
    type: Schemas.Course
}
```

if you really want to use your database in `SQL way` , there's handy package `[publish composite][1]` which will help you `join (artificially)` your tables/collections.